# Groovy- Difference between 2 month

Tags: groovy, logic

I wanted to write simple groovy script which will give the different of 2 months (note: its not date).

For Example

`int startMonth=1 //for Jan`

`int endMonth=3 //for March`

the response should be `2` which is straightforward (Jan > Feb > March)

But in case  :

`int startMonth=11 //for Nov`

`int endMonth=1 //for Jan`

also, then the response should be `2` i.e. the difference of month (Nov > Dec > Jan)

Can you please let me know if there is any function or any easy workaround to implement this? I am using it in Oracle VBCS Groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a groovy question and more of a logic question. One way to do this would be:

```
int distanceInMonths(int a, int b) {
    def min = Math.min(a,b)
    def max = Math.max(a,b)

    Math.min(max - min, 12 + min - max)
}

assert distanceInMonths(1, 3)   == 2
assert distanceInMonths(11, 1)  == 2
assert distanceInMonths(12, 1)  == 1
assert distanceInMonths(12, 12) == 0
assert distanceInMonths(1, 1)   == 0
assert distanceInMonths(1, 12)  == 1
assert distanceInMonths(12, 6)  == 6
```

where all the assertions pass.